# XPages:How to set dojo grid item selected after XSP.partialRefreshPost

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages, dojox.grid

I am using Dojo EnhancedGrid and would like to set an item selected after calling XSP.partialRefreshPost or XSP.partialRefreshGet

```
 var store = dataGrid.store;
    index = grid.selection.selectedIndex;
    var item = dataGrid.getItem(index);
    var id = store.getValue(item, "@unid");
    var remoteMethod = myRPC.sortGridPosition(index + 'DOWN');
    remoteMethod.addCallback(function(response){
        // handle whatever came back from the server

        XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:gridDiv}",{
            onComplete: function () {
            grid.selection.setSelected(response, true);
            grid.selection.setSelected(parseInt(index), false);
        }   
        });
    });
```

but i keep geting the error cannot find focusView of undefined,
how can i set index selected after XSP.partialRefreshPost?

Comment: Hmm, you are using *response* in your *partialRefreshPost*. Isn't this variable undefined?

Comment: the response is just the variable that hold the return value from  remoteMethod

Comment: But you are using *response* in your *onComplete* of your partial refresh. This is a callback method, and *response* is *undefined* in this method (which is thrown in your error).